# Вырезать текст из предложения

Tags: php

Есть большое предложение, из которого нужно вырезать такую часть:

```
<p class="migxPrice">тут всегда разный текст</p>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = '123 <p class="migxPrice">тут всегда разный текст</p> 321';
$text = preg_replace('#<p class="migxPrice">.*</p>#isU', '', $text);
var_dump($text);
```

Так?

Comment: а зачем модификатор `U` ?

Comment: @Эдуард ну например для таких случаев: `123 <p class="migxPrice">тут всегда разный текст</p> 321 <p>текст, который не надо удалять</p>`

Comment: А разве в задаче сказано об удалении только одного вхождения? Кстати, инвертирующий жадность  модификатор `U` не рекомендуется к использованию. В preg_replace() для ограничения количества заменяемых подстрок достаточно будет передать это количество четвёртым аргументом.

Comment: @Manitikyl, первое вхождение можно удалить заменив `.*` => `.*?`

Comment: @Эдуард такс, вы видимо не совсем понимаете как работает модификатор `U`. И никто не заступился :<. Сразу оговорюсь что именно в НАШЕМ случае, `U` и `.*?` - действительно будут эквивалентны, но задачи у них разные. По поводу `не рекомендуется` - не соглашусь. Так что-же он делает? Он удаляет не одно вхождение, а выделяет самый минимальный (первый) кусок (который соответствует регулярке), `U` - не задает количество. Возьмите мой пример и вот такой текст `1<p class="migxPrice">---</p>2<p>3</p>4<p class="migxPrice">---</p>5<p>6</p>` - и посмотрите результат с `U` и без.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie агась, спасибо. А разница? конкретно в этом примере. Эти 2 записи (ваш и мой) - эквивалентны.

Comment: @Эдуард `одного вхождения`, И после вы продолжаете о кол-ве 4ым параметром. Разве не так? если нет - то поясните, что вы имели в виду, и с чего вы взяли что `U` - не рекомендуется.

Comment: @Эдуард, все же бывают случаи когда в нем нуждаются.

Comment: @Эдуард Давайте по порядку: 1) Вы не пояснили свою позицию по поводу кол-ва. Яб сделал вид что забыл, но просто вы так сильно настаиваете, даже заминусовали ответ, это значит вы сильно убеждены что вы правы - я готов выслушать вас по этому поводу. 2) `не рекомендуется к использованию` и `я настоятельно не рекомендую` - 2 разных мнения. 3) И действительно, вы правильно подметили что модификатор `U` меняет `жадных` на `нежадных` и наоборот - В этом и заключается его смысл. То что вы путаетесь, ваши проблемы в которые я не лезу, но хочется узнать причем тут `U`, `одного вхождения` и 4ый параметр.

Comment: @Эдуард Вы уже второй раз, "промахиваетесь" и все пытаетесь научить меня писать регулярки, не надоело? в первый раз мне удалось вас прояснить. А сейчас только и делаете что соскакиваете с ответа, вас конкретно и прямо спросили в чем смысл(логика) вашей фразы, а вы то не отвечаете, то троллинг, то идите читайте. Но я понял вашу проблему, у вас проблема с русским. Я поясню второй пункт для вас: `не рекомендуется к использованию` - кем-то/чем-то (обычно авторитетными людьми либо каким-то обоснованием); `я настоятельно не рекомендую`- ваше личное мнение связанное с тем что вы путаетесь в букавке U

Comment: @Эдуард а причем тут `одно вхождение` и 4ый параметр? Пора-бы уже признаться) Опять отмаза, теперь я деградирую. Где вы суть пытались донести? Все что было - отмазы. То что вы тыкнули в литературу - просто сказали, что я и так знал, меняет местами, молодец! Я не увидел там слов, что не рекомендуется. Я только увидел `На МОЙ взгляд .. поэтому Я настоятельно не рекомендую`. Вы с логикой вообще не дружите?